# Families over Artin Rings and Deformations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory

Let us work with a class of schemes over an algebraically closed field $k$ such that any two schemes in this class are isomorphic.

An example of such a class would be genus zero nonsingular curves over $k$. Let $X$ act as a representative of this class.

Is the set of isomorphism classes of such families over an Artin ring $A$ equivalent to the set of isomorphism classes deformations of $X$ over $A$?

The only problem I am encountering with verifying such a statement is we allow families $\mathcal{X}$ over $B$ to have varying fibers while a deformation fixes the fiber.

** Please assume any nice property you may wish. I did not want to specify the class to be nonsingular genus zero curves because I do not want $H^1(X, \mathcal{T}X) =(0)$., i.e I am interested in scheme which have nontrivial deformations.**